# How can we see the microstructure of steel samples at room temperature?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, metals

When we intend to see the microstructure of a steel sample at a temperature say 950 $^\circ$C they say we quench it in order to freeze the microstructure. However, if we quench it are we not going to have Martensite formation? Again if we anneal it are we going to see the microstructure at room temperature or at 950$^\circ$C. What is the way out? How do I see the microstructure that I wish to see (the ones at elevated temperatures) at room temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By choosing the correct quench rate for the alloy at hand, you will indeed freeze into the metal the microstructure it had at the temperature at which you began the quench. Different quench rates will yield different microstructures, with the slowest quench rate producing room temperature microstructure.

In all cases, the microstructure is studied in the lab after the quench with a *metallographic microscope* which uses reflected light, confocal with the microscope's optical path, and sometimes polarizing filters.

Before inspecting the quenched part with the microscope, it must first be polished to mirror smoothness and then subjected to a selective *grain boundary etch* to resolve the microstructure. These processes are carried out in an *electrochemical etch bath*.

Comment: That was just the answer I was looking for but if varieties of microstrucuture are produced then is there any way we can predict what happened at the elevated temperature?

Comment: Certainly, this is the basis of modern metallurgy. Do you have access to the materials science texts by Van Vlack or Shakelford?